# Sort XML document

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
    <Song><Name>My Song 2.mp3</Name><Year>2007</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>320</Bitrate><Length>04:55</Length><Size>4,80</Size></Song>
    <Song><Name>My Song 1.mp3</Name><Year>2009</Year><Genre>Electro</Genre><Bitrate>192</Bitrate><Length>06:44</Length><Size>8,43</Size></Song>
    <Song><Name>My Song 3.mp3</Name><Year>2008</Year><Genre>UK Hardcore</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Length>05:12</Length><Size>4,20</Size></Song>
</Songs>
```

How I can reorder the list elements by their "Name" property to get an xml document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!--XML Songs Database.-->
<Songs>
    <Song><Name>My Song 1.mp3</Name><Year>2009</Year><Genre>Electro</Genre><Bitrate>192</Bitrate><Length>06:44</Length><Size>8,43</Size></Song>
    <Song><Name>My Song 2.mp3</Name><Year>2007</Year><Genre>Dance</Genre><Bitrate>320</Bitrate><Length>04:55</Length><Size>4,80</Size></Song>
    <Song><Name>My Song 3.mp3</Name><Year>2008</Year><Genre>UK Hardcore</Genre><Bitrate>128</Bitrate><Length>05:12</Length><Size>4,20</Size></Song>
</Songs>
```

This is what I'm trying... :

```
Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlfile)
Dim Elements As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xml.Descendants()

xml = Elements.OrderBy(Function(name) name...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute, but simple approach:

```
xml.Root.ReplaceNodes(xml.Root.Elements("Song") _
                              .OrderBy(Function (s) s.Element("Name").Value))
```

Comment: Can't be done using LINQ but without realligning the original xdocument? I mean to store the sorted document into other var without changes in the original xdocument (dim sorted_xml = xml.Root.ReplaceNodes...)

Comment: `Dim copy As XDocument = New XDocument(xml)`  `copy.Root.ReplaceNodes(copy. ...`