# Sort an XML preserving whitespace/indentation?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, linq, sorting

I have an XML formatting like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<!--MasterMusik Video Database-->
<Videos>
  <Video><Name>SKRILLEX &amp; WOLFGANG GARTNER - THE DEVIL's DEN</Name><Genre>Techno</Genre><Format>mp4</Format><HD>HD</HD><Resolution>1280x720</Resolution><Size>70,57</Size></Video>
  <Video><Name>4 Strings - Let It Rain</Name><Genre>Dance</Genre><Format>mp4</Format><HD>HD</HD><Resolution>1920x1080</Resolution><Size>129,3</Size></Video>
  <Video><Name>Deadmau5 - I Remember (Live At Roskilde Festival)</Name><Genre>Trance</Genre><Format>mkv</Format><HD>SD</HD><Resolution>704x384</Resolution><Size>97,99</Size></Video>
</Videos>
```

I would like to sort the elements by their "Name" tag.

This is the function I'm using to sort the elements [Sort XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567748/sort-xml-document)

```
Private Function XML_Sort(ByVal xdoc As XDocument, _
                          ByVal Root_Element As String, _
                          ByVal Element_to_sort As String) As XDocument

    Try

        xdoc.Root.ReplaceNodes(xdoc.Root.Elements(Root_Element) _
                              .OrderBy(Function(sort) sort.Element(Element_to_sort).Value))

        Return xdoc

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Function
```

But the output that I get is totally indented:

```
<!--MasterMusik Video Database-->
<Videos>
  <Video>
    <Name>4 Strings - Let It Rain</Name>
    <Genre>Dance</Genre>
    <Format>mp4</Format>
    <HD>HD</HD>
    <Resolution>1920x1080</Resolution>
    <Size>129,3</Size>
  </Video>
  <Video>
    <Name>Deadmau5 - I Remember (Live At Roskilde Festival)</Name>
    <Genre>Trance</Genre>
    <Format>mkv</Format>
    <HD>SD</HD>
    <Resolution>704x384</Resolution>
    <Size>97,99</Size>
  </Video>
  <Video>
    <Name>SKRILLEX &amp; WOLFGANG GARTNER - THE DEVIL's DEN</Name>
    <Genre>Techno</Genre>
    <Format>mp4</Format>
    <HD>HD</HD>
    <Resolution>1280x720</Resolution>
    <Size>70,57</Size>
  </Video>
</Videos>
```

This is the usage that I'm using:

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = _
    XDocument.Load("Videos.xml", LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)

xdoc = XML_Sort(xdoc, "Video", "Name")

IO.File.WriteAllText("Sorted Videox.xml", xdoc.ToString)
```

Two problems at this point:

1. The output is indented.
2. The declaration of the XML is not written `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>`, I need to write it manually.

How I can fix both problems?

Comment: To save the XML you can simply use [`XDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb551426.aspx). This will write valid XML including the header (`ToString` removes the header).

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need the XML formatted in this way. It sounds like a problem with the consuming code.

Comment: @Ian Nelson It's a file-size question, the filesize of the code with the formatting is 12 mb instead 20 mb using the "normal" formatting, it is not much difference (At the moment) but the most important thing is that I can read/find better the information of each file written inside the XML if each file/atributes are grouped in one line like you can see in the XML formatting example at the top of this question, but after trying to sort the XML elements I lost that formatting. PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: `Catch ex As Exception: Throw New Exception(ex.Message)` ... all this does is to destroy the stack trace and the Exception type information. Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you start manipulating your `XDocument`, the formatting gets lost. Your sorting method just returns a list of pure XML elements. Thus, you have two options:

1. Sort the file with text comparisons. That shouldn't be too hard, since `<Name>` is the first tag in the line, so simply sorting the *text lines* alphabetically should suffice:

   ```
   Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("Videos.xml")
   Dim toSort = lines.Skip(3).Take(lines.Length - 4)   ' skip first three and last line '
   Dim result =
       lines.Take(3).Concat(toSort.OrderBy(Function(s) s)).Concat({lines.Last})
   File.WriteAllLines("Sorted.xml", result.ToArray())
   ```
2. Alternatively, do your sorting (or whatever else you want to do) using XDocument, but use your own output routine:

   ```
   Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
   sb.AppendLine("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""Windows-1252""?>")
   sb.AppendLine("<!--MasterMusic Video Database-->")
   sb.AppendLine("<Videos>")
   For Each video In xdoc.Root.Elements
       sb.AppendLine("  " & video.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting))
   Next
   sb.AppendLine("</Videos>")
   File.WriteAllText("Sorted.xml", sb.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
   ```

Comment: Thankyou, then now is solved, I will accept this answer, until 23 hours the bounty says that I can't.

Comment: could you fix the last line arguments? the first arguments is a file path, the second is the sb, and the last is the Encoding but the `New Encoding(1252)` argument it says that new can't be used. then how to save the file to that ANSI encoding?

Comment: @ElektroStudios: Thanks, fixed. The correct syntax is to call `Encoding.GetEncoding`. The `Encoding(int)` constructor is protected.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
IO.File.WriteAllText("Sorted Videox.xml", xdoc.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting))
```

Comment: Thankyou but don't worked, I get an "AllInOne line" without any formatting.